# Double enter while writing comments

Tags: bug, comments

If I'm creating a comment and right click (usually I use the keyboard's "right click" button) on a misspelled word I get a dialog like this:

[image: Screenshot of a context menu on a misspelled word, with suggestions for correct spellings]

If I then select the correct spelling using my keyboard and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, the word will be corrected but the comment will also be submitted. I'd expect <kbd>enter</kbd> to not do two actions like that. Instead I'd expect the word to be corrected and I would be able to continue writing my comment.

When writing an answer/question this same action doesn't trigger a "double enter".

This happens in Firefox (58 now, but has been happening for a long time) on Windows.

My `about:config` setting `layout.spellcheckDefault` has a value of `1`, the default.

Comment: Spellchecking is not normally enabled in comments in Firefox, have you set the layout.spellcheckDefault pref to some non-default value?

Comment: I can repro.  I get spellchecking on Firefox 58 as well as Chrome 63, and I haven't set any spellcheck to something non-default.  And on Chrome the above corrects the word without submitting ... on Firefox it does submit the comment.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's been happening in FF for as long as I can remember I thought. I haven't changed any default settings (see my edit, pretty sure that's default as it's not bold in config).

Comment: onkeyup binding?

Comment: @Phil there is indeed a keyUp binding that submits the form on enter press as long as shift is not pressed.

Funny, I wasn't aware you could actually introduce newlines in comments by holding down shift. Doesn't in the end render them though :)

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63644/476

Comment: status-bydesign

Comment: This sounds like the same bug as *[Confirming context menu entries via Enter when entering comments triggers comment to be posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66646/confirming-context-menu-entries-via-enter-when-entering-comments-triggers-commen)*. If so, my [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script / extension should fix it (among lots of other things). Can you test it and tell me if it works?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Just installed SOUP and now attempting a misspelling. Hah!  It worked! Much obliged :)

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this in chrome (you can use SHIFT+F10 to open the spallchacking tool).

Comment: As an android user with non-english as native language, My virtual keyboard for english has some very nasty auto correct, which usually I use the virtual enter to dismiss, but on so comments, it auto submit the comments, whcih keeps annoying me.